# Unable to Refer to Listbox on Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I haven't used list boxes before and don't need to use objects too often in my work, but for some reason, my code runs OK for this:

```
ActiveSheet.ListBox1.AddItem MyName(i)
```

but if I try to get the listbox using a worksheet instead of the ActiveSheet, it errors

```
wkTest.ListBox1.AddItem MyName(i)
```

Where test is the worksheet on which ListBox1 lives. What is the best way to reference a listbox if you want to refer it to it based on the sheet it's? Or is this not the right way to go about doing this.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Post the error code and description please. Is wkTest a worksheet variable or the property name of the sheet? Is the listbox an Excel object or an ActiveX (i.e. older style) object?

Comment: If you declared `wkTest` as a `Worksheet` you will get an error because the worksheet class does not have a `Listbox1` property. Declare it as `Object` or as the code name of the sheet in question.

Comment: Echoing @Rory, a quick workaround in some instances is simply to use `Worksheets("SheetName").ListBox1...`. If you need to do a lot with the ListBox, just use `With`.

Answer (score 2):

### Shortcomings of the List Box ActiveX Control?

**Setup**

- Open a new worksheet and in the `Developers` tab click on `Insert`
  and under `ActiveX Controls` click on `List Box (ActiveX Control)`.
- "Draw" the control onto the worksheet. Copy the following code into a
  standard module (e.g. `Module1`).

**Conclusions**

- The first part of the code demonstrates that although you can access
  the `ListBox` by its name via the `Shapes` and `OLEObjects collections`,
  both do not provide a way to add items to the `ListBox`.
- The only way to do this seems to be to use the `CodeName`, which is
  demonstrated through various solutions in the second part of the
  code.

This was inspired by the ideas from [Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611989/rory) and [Michael Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10821072/michael-smith) in the comments.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListBoxTest()

    ' Worksheet
    Dim wkTest As Worksheet: Set wkTest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Shape - no use
    Dim shTest As Shape: Set shTest = wkTest.Shapes("ListBox1")
    Debug.Print "Shape", shTest.Name, shTest.Left
    'shTest.AddItem "One" 'Run-time Error '438': Object doesn't support ...

    ' OLEObject - no use
    Dim ooTest As OLEObject: Set ooTest = wkTest.OLEObjects("ListBox1")
    Debug.Print "OLEObject", ooTest.Name, ooTest.Left
    'ooTest.AddItem "One" 'Run-time Error '438': Object doesn't support ...

    Dim obj As Object

    'Set obj = wkTest.ListBox1 ' Compile error: Method or data member not found.

    ' Object 1 Solution
    Set obj = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListBox1
    Debug.Print "Object 1", obj.Name, obj.Left
    obj.AddItem "One"

    ' Object 2 Solution
    Set obj = Sheet1.ListBox1
    Debug.Print "Object 2", obj.Name, obj.Left
    obj.AddItem "Two"

    ' Object 3 Solution
    wkTest.Activate
    Set obj = ActiveSheet.ListBox1
    Debug.Print "Object 3", obj.Name, obj.Left
    obj.AddItem "Three"

    ' Favorite
    With Sheet1.ListBox1
        Debug.Print "Favorite", .Name, .Left
        .AddItem "Four"
    End With

End Sub

Sub ListBoxClear()
    Dim obj As Object: Set obj = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListBox1
    obj.Clear
End Sub
```